# Отслеживание координат SVG

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, координаты

При попытке реализации зумирования SVG области (путём изменения координат viewBox) стал вопрос о том, как именно мы можем отследить изменение полученных координат по сранению с первоначальным ?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно вас понял, вам нужна функция getBoundingClientRect(), которая показывает расположение элемента. Отслеживать можно, разумеется через переменные